# Sql Exception no displaying in messagebox

Tags: c#, sql, messagebox

I'm getting a SQL exception when trying to insert a duplicate but the SQL error is not being sent to the message box. I can see the error in the debug.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using static AccountManager.productinsert.BusinessLogic;

namespace AccountManager
{
  public partial class ProductAdd : Form
  {
    public ProductAdd()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void CleartextBoxes1()
    {
      ProductId.Clear();
      ProductName.Clear();            
      ProductPrice.Clear();
    }

    private void BtnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      this.Close();
    }

    private void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      try
      {
        var product = new ProductDetails();
        product.ProductId = ProductId.Text;
        product.ProductName = ProductName.Text;
        product.ProductPrice = ProductPrice.Text;
        AddProduct(product);

        MessageBox.Show("Product Created!");
        CleartextBoxes1();
      }
      catch (SqlException)
      {
          MessageBox.Show("Product Already Exists");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The error from the debug is

> Exception Exception caught: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in
>   AccountManager.exe ("Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint
>   'UQ__Products__B40CC6CC7010A856'. Cannot insert duplicate key in
>   object 'dbo.Products'. The duplicate key value is (1). The statement
>   has been terminated.")    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Code for add product as requested

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace AccountManager
{
    class productinsert
    {

        public class BusinessLogic
        {
            public static void AddProduct(ProductDetails details)
            {
                using (SqlConnection openCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=AccountMGR;Integrated Security=True;"))
                {
                    var statement = "insert into Products(" +
                           "  ProductId, ProductName, Price)" +
                           " values(" +
                           "  @ProductId," +
                           "  @ProductName," +
                           "  @Price)";



                    using (SqlCommand queryInsert = new SqlCommand(statement))
                    {
                        queryInsert.Connection = openCon;

                        queryInsert.Parameters.Add("@ProductId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = details.ProductId;
                        queryInsert.Parameters.Add("@ProductName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = details.ProductName;
                        queryInsert.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = details.ProductPrice;



                        openCon.Open();
                        try
                        {
                            queryInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        catch (SqlException)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }


            }




            public class ProductDetails
            {

                public string ProductId { get; set; } = "";
                public string ProductName { get; set; } = "";
                public string ProductPrice { get; set; } = "";


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what happens if you hit F5 to continue the debugger?

Comment: catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Product Already Exists. " + ex.Message);
            }

Comment: @Kevin you should post this as an answer so it can be accepted and you can win fun and amazing stuff!

Comment: @CodeCaster Nothing. Ive tried that. I just get the box to say product created

Comment: Can you please post the source of `AddProduct`? It is possible it is wrapping or hiding the exception.

Comment: If client doesn't use `ProductId` an easy workaround this is making `ProductId` and `Identity` column, and make db autoincrement the value

Comment: @Kobi ive added the code as you asked

Comment: If you want to catch and show the exception in the UI, you will have to remove the empty try/catch block in the business logic class

Comment: @LennartStoop No difference

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
try
{
     SaveData();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     var sqlException = ex.InnerException as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException;

     if (sqlException.Number == 2601)
     {
         MessageBox.show("Product Already Exists");
     }
     else
     {
         MessageBox.show(ex.Message());
     }
}
```

2627 is for Unique constraint error

2601 is for Duplicated key row error

I hope this will help you!

Answer (score 1):

you should catch the `SqlException` before  the General `Exception`. and define an object instance of your `SqlException`, the below code would solce your problem:

```
try
{
    queryInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (SqlException e)
{

    if (exc.Number == 2601)
    {
        MessageBox.show("Your Record is already exists");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.show(e.Message());
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // other kind of exception
}
```

**Notes:**

> 2601 means Duplicated key row error
>
> 2627 means Unique constraint error

Answer (score 1):

You should throw exception to catch if you have used try catch

```
try
{
    queryInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch 
{
   throw;
}
```